# Convert javascript ticks to date in Flot jQuery-plugin issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, flot

I have a dynamic Flot graph with dates on the x-axis and numbers on the y-axis. To get the Flot-plugin to read the date object correctly, I had to convert the dates to ticks (with `getTime()`). My problem is that I can't revers the ticks back to a normal date in my tooltip hover on the graph.
[image]

I've tried to revers it with this:

```
dateTimeObject = new Date((jsTicks - 621355968000000000) / 10000);
```

All I get, no matter what jsTicks is, is "Jan 02 0001 hh:mm:ss (almost current time)"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This somewhat depends on whether you accounted for the browser's timezone or not when you were creating the data.  A simplistic way to deal with this in a `plotclick` or `plothover` event is like so:

```
$("#placeholder").bind("plotclick", function(event, pos, item) {
    var x = item.datapoint[0],
    y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);
    var dt = new Date(x);
    var label = 'At '+dt.toLocaleTimeString()+' ';
    //now display this label
}
```

If you are accounting for timezone in your data, you'd need to have one that looks more like this:

```
$("#placeholder").bind("plotclick", function(event, pos, item) {
    var x = item.datapoint[0],
    y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);
    var userTZ = new Date();
    userTZ = userTZ.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000;
    var dt = new Date(x+userTZ);
    var label = 'At '+dt.toLocaleTimeString()+' ';
    //now display this label
}
```

An example with timezones in place:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/utNaJ/

Comment: Excelent! Also, if you only want the date and not the time, just replace
dt.LocaleTimeString()
to
dt.toLocaleDateString()